# Extract hour and use it on a command

Tags: javascript, discord, hour

i want that when i react to a message it edit the embed the hour is it  [There is and error but i know how to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW36s.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what i mean is how to put the hour in the message, for example, is know 11:51 and i react to the message so at the message appear 11:51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution, is easy, just make a let call:
let time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
and later in the message put:  <t:${time}>